# Not able to stream websocket data to frontend

Tags: python, callback, flask-socketio

I am trying to stream market live data from a stock broker (Zerodha) via their websockets sdk, to my frontend.

I am able to log the live data in my python console, but I am not able to stream it to the frontend.

I am new to the socket programming, so please kindly excuse.

Below is the python snippet.

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session   
import threading
import time
from kiteconnect import KiteTicker #WebSocket client for connecting to Kite Connect's streaming quotes service.
import logging

###
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
###
app = Flask(__name__)
##
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode= 'threading')
##
app.config['DEBUG'] = False


ticker = None
@app.route('/streamData')
def streamData():
    '''
    to start stream we first have to  
    1.) initiliase a WS connection - done
    2.) Subscribe/register the symbols - done
    3.) Check on new ticks - done
    4.) To do: kill the ws after x time
    '''
    global ticker
    
    accessToken = getAccessToken()
    ticker = KiteTicker("api key here", accessToken)#1

    # Assign the callbacks.
    ticker.on_connect = onConnectLocal
    ticker.on_close = onDisconnectLocal
    ticker.on_error = onErrorLocal
    ticker.on_ticks = onNewTicksLocal#3

    logging.info('Ticker: Going to connect..')
    ticker.connect(threaded=True)
    time.sleep(5)
    symbols = ['stock', 'names', 'given', 'here']
    tokens = []
    kite = getKite()
    fetchInstruments(kite)
    for symbol in symbols:
        isd = getInstrumentDataBySymbol(symbol)
        token = isd['instrument_token']
        logging.info('registerSymbol: %s token = %s', symbol, token)
    tokens.append(token)
    
    logging.info('Subscribing tokens %s', tokens)
    ticker.subscribe(tokens)#2
    print(tokens)
    return render_template('stream.html', async_mode='threading') # here is where I want to stream the data 
    
def onConnectLocal(ws, response):
    logging.info('Ticker connection successful.')

def onDisconnectLocal(ws, code, reason):
    logging.error('Ticker got disconnected. code = %d, reason = %s', code, reason)

def onErrorLocal(ws, code, reason):
    logging.error('Ticker errored out. code = %d, reason = %s', code, reason)

#@socketio.on('my_broadcast_event', namespace='/test')
def onNewTicksLocal(ws, ticks):#3 # this the method which streams data from the broker's websocket
    for tick in ticks:
        isd = getInstrumentDataByToken(tick['instrument_token']) 
        symbol = isd['tradingsymbol']
        logging.info('Tick: %s CMP = %f', symbol, tick['last_price']) #this prints to the python console with no problem
        socketio.emit('my_response',{'data': tick}, broadcast=True)# this makes the problem

app.run('localhost', 8080)
```

stream.html (frontend)

```
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            namespace = 'http://localhost:8080/streamData';
            var socket = io(namespace);

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('my_event', {data: 'connected to the SocketServer...'});
            });

            socket.on('my_response', function(msg, cb) {
                $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('logs #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
                if (cb)
                    cb();
            });
            $('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
                socket.emit('my_event', {data: $('#emit_data').val()});
                return false;
            });
            $('form#broadcast').submit(function(event) {
                socket.emit('my_broadcast_event', {data: $('#broadcast_data').val()});
                return false;
            });
            $('form#disconnect').submit(function(event) {
                socket.emit('disconnect_request');
                return false;
            });

            socket.on('my_response', function(data){
            console.log(data.msg)
            socket.emit('my_response', {data: data.msg});

 });
        });

        

    </script>
```

The error i get always is :-

```
TypeError: onNewTicksLocal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ticks'
```

But as you can see above I have supplied this(I get this error when I click on the broadcast button).

Please let me know where I am going wrong (I feel, but not certain, I could be going wrong with the callbacks).

edit :- updated the html code & port number in python

Comment: You seem to be mixing the API from your stock broker with Socket.IO. The `onNewTicksLocal()` is a callback for your stock broker, it does not need to be Socket.IO event handler.

Comment: i commented out the @socketio.on('my_broadcast_event', namespace='/test'), it does not give any error, but this does not stream/display any data to the frontend...

Comment: You are using a namespace called `/test`. If you want your client to receive the event you have to emit on the same namespace. Also your client does not appear to have a `my_response` event handler.

Comment: @Miguel, sorry I had not given the right html code orginally. I have made the update to the question. But I am still not able to get any data in the console.log

Comment: Ok, I got it working. At the client side i just had to use  namespace = 'http://localhost:8080/ & the data is streaming.